# Paper showing that logistic regression intercept biased in rare events

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, references, bias, rare-events

I'm studying the logistic regression for estimate the Probability of Default of SME's. Fortunately the event (firm's default) is a rare event.

King and Zeng tell us that "logistic regression can sharply underestimate the probability of rare events" (Logistic regression in rare events data, 2001). This is because the logistic regression coefficient is biased in these situations.

Could someone tell me in which paper is proved that the logistic regression intercept is biased when the event (Y=1) is rare.

Comment: Link for those interested: http://gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/0s-abs.shtml

Comment: Don't the McCullagh & Nelder GLM book cited in @Tim's link and the appendices in King et al's paper contain the proofs?

Comment: Thanks @Dimitriy, I saw the proof on the appendices but I hoped to find another one simpler. I'll check the one on the McCullagh&Nelder book cited in King and Zeng paper.

Comment: I checked, but the main problem for me is conceptual: since the logistic regression belong to the GLM's family, we know that the estimation of the parameters is done through the Fisher scoring algorithm and that there isn't a closed formula for the estimator. So if this is true, how could I now that the intercept is biased?

Comment: @LucaDibo Take a look at pp. 703-704 of [King and Zheng paper](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/baby0s.pdf#Page=11) for the intuition on the single regressor case.

Comment: Logit is one of the main tools to model defaults, btw.

Comment: yes @Aksakal I know..but you can't use random sapling…you have to use a case-control sampling. If you use random sapling the coefficients are biased also in big sample. So the problem here is that if you use the case-control sample, then the intercept is biased, but the other parameters are consistent. I can't understand the proof

Comment: In my case, we don't sample. We collect all the mortgages that are available.