# How should I perform explanatory logistic regression modelling of the relationship between a rare outcome and a rare predictor variable?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, rare-events

Are there any general guidelines for conducting explanatory (rather than predictive) logistic regression analysis when both the outcome variable and the predictor variable of interest are rare events?

I will be conducting a pooled regression analysis of around 50,000 general population survey responses, in order to understand the role of variable $x$ in increasing the frequency of $y=1$. $x=1$ in around 2.5% of responses, and $y=1$ in around 8% of cases.

So even under the null hypothesis of no association, we'd expect around 100 cases where $x=1 \wedge y=1$. From previous studies of treatment seeking convenience populations, we'd expect the odds ratio of $y=1$ given that $x=1$ to be in the range of 1.5 - 10.0. So the number of cases where$x=1 \wedge y=1$ is likely to be around the 150 - 1000 mark (I don't have access to these data yet).

I have previously been told that logistic regression does not perform well when the outcome variable is unbalanced. I have been told by a respected statistician that in this situation I should combine all of the cases where $y=1$ with a subsample of the cases where $y=0$ in order to balance the data set. However, [Frank Harrell](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96999/frequency-weights-rare-events-and-logistic-regression#comment189273_96999) and [others](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67903/does-down-sampling-change-logistic-regression-coefficients) suggest that once the data has been collected, it would be a mistake to discard it except for computational reasons.

In this case, *both* the outcome variable and the predictor variable of interest are unbalanced. Are there any guidelines for analysis under these conditions?

Please note that I am not interested in [mathematical proofs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126803/paper-showing-that-logistic-regression-intercept-biased-in-rare-events) about biased estimators or the like. Rather, I am interested in guidelines for applied researchers about how to deal with real-world datasets like this.